# pointwise convergence of a filter on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, intuition, filters

In my topology lecture we have defined pointwise convergence for filters on function spaces, say $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$. A filter $\varphi$ on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ converges pointwise to $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ if for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ the filter generated by $\{F(x): F\in\varphi\}$ (where $F(x):=\{f(x): f\in F\}$) converges to $g(x)$.

I have no intuition what this means. Can someone breath life into this definition?

Comment: Do you know what it means for a sequence of functions to converge pointwise?  This is what happens when you adapt that definition to convergence of filters.  I think your difficulty is probably not pointwise convergence, but instead convergence of filters in general.

Comment: @GEdgar I know what pointwise convergence for function sequences means and I have an intuition of that (something like graphs in x-y-planes that evolve in z-direction (i.e. the n) and then I take a slice at some point x and consider the points on the corresponding y-z-plane). I also think that I understand filter convergence. I imagine the filter like a (inverted) mountain range generated by the set inclusion partial order and then the limit resp. the singleton containing the limit is the infimum of the filter, or in pictures, the peak of the mountain. Is this appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a sequence $\sigma=\langle f_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of elements of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$; we say that this sequence converges pointwise to $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ if for each $x\in\Bbb R$, the coordinate sequence $\langle f_n(x):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $g(x)$ in $\Bbb R$. Let’s look at that in a more general light.

As a set, $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ is the Cartesian product of $|\Bbb R|$ copies of $\Bbb R$. When we look at $f(x)$ for some $f\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$, we’re looking at the projection of $f$ on the $x$ factor of this product. If we let $R_x=\Bbb R$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$, then $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ is simply $\prod_{x\in\Bbb R}R_x$, and for each $y\in\Bbb R$ we can define the projection map

$$\pi_y:\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}=\prod_{x\in\Bbb R}R_x \to R_y(=\Bbb R):f\mapsto f(y)\;.$$

From this point of view the coordinate sequence $\langle f_n(x):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is just the projection of $\sigma$ on the $x$-factor: it’s $\sigma_x=\langle\pi_x(f_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$. Thus, we say that $\sigma$ converges pointwise to $g$ if and only if for each $x\in\Bbb R$, the projection $\sigma_x$ of $\sigma$ on the $x$ factor converges to $g(x)$.

Pointwise convergence for filters on function spaces is a generalization of this idea. Instead of the sequence $\sigma$, we now have some filter $\varphi$ on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$. Each $F\in\varphi$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$, i.e., some set of functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. Equivalently, it’s a subset of the Cartesian $\prod_{x\in\Bbb R}R_x$. As such it has a projection on each factor of this product: for each $x\in\Bbb R$ the projection of $F$ on $R_x$ is

$$\pi_x[F]=\{f(x):f\in F\}\;.$$

Let $\mathscr{B}_x=\{\pi_x[F]:F\in\varphi\}$; this is a collection of subsets of $R_x=\Bbb R$. When we projected the sequence $\sigma$ to $R_x$, we automatically got a sequence in $R_x$, i.e., a sequence of real numbers. Unfortunately, the projection $\mathscr{B}_x$ of the filter $\varphi$ on $R_x$ is not necessarily a filter. It *is*, however, a filter base:

- for any $B_0,B_1\in\mathscr{B}_x$ there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}_x$ such that $B\subseteq B_0\cap B_1$. (This is an easy consequence of the fact that $\varphi$ is a filter, and I’ll leave its proof to you.)

This means that $\mathscr{B}_x$ generates a unique filter $\varphi_x$ on $R_x$ in the following way: let

$$\mathscr{B}_x'=\left\{\bigcap\mathscr{A}:\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{B}_x\text{ is finite}\right\}\;,$$

the closure of $\mathscr{B}_x$ under finite intersections, and set $\varphi_x=\{A\subseteq R_x:\exists B\in\mathscr{B}_x'(B\subseteq A)\}$, the closure of $\mathscr{B}_x'$ under supersets. You can easily check that $\varphi_x$ is a filter on $R_x=\Bbb R$.

Now we can say that the filter $\varphi$ on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ converges pointwise to $g\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ if and only if for each $x\in\Bbb R$, the filter $\varphi_x$ generated by the projection of $\varphi$ on the $x$ factor converges to $g(x)$. It really is exactly the same basic idea as pointwise convergence of sequences of functions.

Comment: Why do we need $\mathscr{B}_x'$? Doesn't it suffice to define the filter $\varphi_x$ as the filter generated by the filter basis  $\mathscr{B}_x$, that is $\varphi_x := \{A\subseteq R_x | \exists B\in\mathscr{B}_x : B \subseteq A\}?$ Does my definition of $\varphi_x$ maybe yield the same filter as in your post?

Comment: @el_tenedor: Yes, $\varphi_x$ is the filter generated by the filter base $\mathscr{B}_x$; I simply chose to describe it in terms of closure operations, since (a) I wasn’t assuming that the OP is familiar with filter bases, and (b) that makes it (I think) slightly more obvious that you actually get a filter.

Comment: I thought a lot about your answer and I think it has helped me.

Comment: @Sebastian: I’m happy to hear it. It takes a while to get used to working with filters, so if you have further questions, don’t hesitate to ask.